# How to remove duplicate entries before redirect to file

Tags: shell-script

I have seen command "uniq" to remove duplicate entries in file but
My purpose is to remove duplicate output before saving in file

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "aaa"
echo "bbb"
echo "aaa"
echo "aaa"
echo "bbb"
echo "ccc"
```

I want to the output to be

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

and then redirect to text file

Is it possible to do this way? Thank you.

Comment: why not removing duplicated commands `echo ….` in your script then?

Answer (score 4):

`uniq` only works on sorted input.

```
./my_script.sh | sort -u > output_file
```

is essentially the same as

```
./my_script.sh | sort | uniq > output_file
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk '!a[$0]++'` is a compact way of removing unsorted duplicated lines, keeping original order.

Using this we can for example:

- filter the output: `./my_script |awk '!a[$0]++' > output`
- filter the script: `awk '!a[$0]++' my_script > new_script`
- filter and execute the script: `awk '!a[$0]++' my_script | sh > output`
- filter inside vim : `:%!awk '\!a[$0]++'`

The idea behind this is to keep track of patterns already found by storing the number of occurences in an array `a` and only printing a line if the value of `a` for the specific content of the line (represented by `$0` in `awk`) is still zero. So,

- `a[$0]++` increments the array entry for the "index" `$0` (= the content of the current input line) by one
- `!a[$0]` is a filter rule that instructs `awk` to only print a line if the array entry for the content is still zero (which is implicitly the case when it is uninitialized)
- `!a[$0]++` combines the two in one line (a.k.a. "code golfing")

...and we can also make it more readable with a bash `alias`:

`alias myuniq='awk '\''!a[$0]++'\'`

---

\thanks{@AdminBee}

Comment: @AdminBee: thank you!